# Disable scrolling when click on tag a without using jQuery

Tags: html, css, scroll

This is my code with effect on click.

When the window has scroll bars and tab contents are not at the top, then I see the window scroll when I click a tab header. I don't want this.

How can I prevent scrolling without using jquery?

*I've added `.contents-above` and `.contents-below` with inline style so the scroll would appear running the snippet*

```css
.tab div {
  display: none;
}

.tab div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents-above" style="height: 5em;">...</div>

<div class="tab">
  <div id="link1">
    <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="link2">
    <h3>Content to Link 2</h3>
    <h4>Great success!</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="link3">
    <h3>Content to Link 3</h3>
    <p>Yeah!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab">

  <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>

</div>

<div class="contents-below" style="height: 5em;">...</div>
```

Comment: Eh? What scroll? In your code is nothing about scrolling, just switching display property.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When I try it, it does not really scroll, the .tab div:target just appears and pushes the links down. An Illusion perhaps.

Comment: I've edited the question hoping it will reopen it: it's a very common and interesting problem when trying to make tabs in pure CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a link with an anchor, page scrolls to that anchor and it becomes `:target`. You relying on that for displaying tabs causes a scroll to the tab when their headers or another link to them is clicked.

You can avoid that by making your target anchor on a hidden element, and then use CSS sibling rules to style your tab to visible

```css
.somestufftoscroll {
  height: 36em;
  background: gray;
}

.tab div {
  display: none;
}

.tab .tab-target:target+div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="linksontop">

  <a href="#linktarget-1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#linktarget-2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#linktarget-3">Link 3</a>

</div>

<div class="somestufftoscroll">
  tabs below this area
</div>

<div class="tab">
  <div id="linktarget-1" class="tab-target" hidden></div>
  <div id="link1">
    <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="linktarget-2" class="tab-target" hidden></div>
  <div id="link2">
    <h3>Content to Link 2</h3>
    <h4>Great success!</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="linktarget-3" class="tab-target" hidden></div>
  <div id="link3">
    <h3>Content to Link 3</h3>
    <p>Yeah!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab">

  <a href="#linktarget-1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#linktarget-2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#linktarget-3">Link 3</a>

</div>
```

Also your naming is confusing

I suggest the following instead:

```css
.somestufftoscroll {
    height: 36em;
    background: gray;
}

.tab-contents {
    display: none;
}

.tabs-contents .tab-target:target + .tab-contents {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-links">
  <a href="#tabtarget-1">Link to tab 1</a>
  <a href="#tabtarget-2">Link to tab 2</a>
  <a href="#tabtarget-3">Link to tab 3</a>
</div>

<div class="somestufftoscroll">
  <p>Tabs below this area</p>
  <p><em>This is here to test scrolling</em></p>
</div>

<div class="tabs-contents">
  <div id="tabtarget-1" class="tab-target" hidden></div>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-contents">
    <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tabtarget-2" class="tab-target" hidden></div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-contents">
    <h3>Content to Link 2</h3>
    <h4>Great success!</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="tabtarget-3" class="tab-target" hidden></div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab-contents">
    <h3>Content to Link 3</h3>
    <p>Yeah!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">

  <a href="#tabtarget-1">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="#tabtarget-2">Tab 2</a>
  <a href="#tabtarget-3">Tab 3</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect man! For desktop this solution is perfect! But for mobile :target not work. When i click nothing happen. Why?

Comment: Target works on mobile. Maybe your browser doesn't agree with the hidden target. You can also try and set it `position: fixed; left: -1000px;` and remove the `hidden` attribute

Comment: Because my tag is this <a href="#tabtarget-1"><div style="width:20px;height:20px;float:left;background:red;"></div></a> and i think when i click for mobile version is empty!

Comment: @Jackom if you want to avoid trouble in html, then quit using floats. With html5/css3, you've got all the tools you need to do layout in a proper and understandable way, easier to read and debug and more stable across browsers. Floats are for embedding contents within text paragraphs, period.